# Unexploded war results in failed deployment in Apache Tomcat 8.0.41

Tags: java-8, tomcat8

My application was deployed on Tomcat 8.0.36 and JDK 1.8.0_111 and was working fine. After the upgrade of Tomcat to 8.0.41 and JDK 1.8.0_121, the deployment fails giving this error. Also I get the following error only when the war is not exploded while deploying. If I set unpackWARs true, then the war gets deployed successfully. Since this client server, unpackWARs cannot be set to true. So I need a solution to deploy the war without exploding it.

```
16:39:12.653 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [war:file:/C:/Users/user123/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/project.war*/WEB-INF/classes/package-path/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [war:file:/C:/Users/user123/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/project.war*/WEB-INF/classes/package-path/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: war:file:/C:/Users/user123/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps/project.war*/WEB-INF/classes/package-path/
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:218) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:607) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:420) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:274) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1269) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.buildDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:523) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.readPersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:503) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:440) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
```

Comment: Had exactly the same issue minutes ago. Found this https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Deployment and will now most likely reconfigure for unpackWAR="true" and test and hope for the best

Comment: With setting unpackWAR=true , the deployment is successful as I have mentioned above. My issue occurs if it is set to false.

Comment: Same here - but running unpacked has been reworked in tomcat as well so most of the reasons behind running directly from war have become obsolete - check details in the link.

Comment: I understand your point. But does this mean that my application wont deploy if the unpacking is disabled?

Comment: It sure feels that way. Spring will isse the error seen if the resource URL does not start with file: - and tomcat 8.x suddenly uses a war:file: url. One of them would need to be changed (and unpacking would change the tomcat part)

Comment: Also one more factor I forgot to mention, this deployment fails only when I use component scan in Spring. If I declare the beans in the Spring config file, the deployment runs fine eventhough if unpackWARs=false. Does this mean that if I declare the beans explicitly then tomcat doesn't need to render the resource file URL to Spring?

Comment: Yes. The errors occurs at component-scanning time - to scan the classes Spring iterates over all classes matched by your component-scan parameters - and it's that resource locator that cannot handle war: resources. It might even work (haven't tried that) to change component-scan prefix to something else (but I don't know what :-( )

Answer (score 0):

got the same issue, according to bugreport on github the problem is with the tomcat version:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7949

The possible workaround which worked perfectly in my case, is instead of putting war file into your tomcat directory, put there already manually unpacked war(or set tomcat unpack property to true)

UPDATE:
sorry, didn't get your question properly, at first. All in all after reading mail list connected to this bug it seems that there is no other way to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. **Explicitly define** all the `<bean class="..."/>` whose classes ale loaded from your *war* project. (Instead of `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>`). Note that this may also improve performance. 
   Strangely enough, component scan worked for beans loaded from another *.jar* project, a deeper service layer - the problem was just with the *war*-level beans.
2. Upgrade to a newer Spring library version (v 4.3.10 does not suffer the issue)
3. Deploy exploded *war* directory, not a zipped *.war* file. But then your app may fail unexpectedly, based on the context of how it's deployed.